# Optimize the query (may be avoid nested loop)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

How can we optimize the following query:

```
select * 
from program_infos pi
join endeavour_organizations seller_organization on seller_organization.id = pi.supplier_id
join endeavour_organizations obligor_organization on obligor_organization.id = pi.buyer_id
join invoices i on pi.program_id = i.program_id
join assets fa on fa.invoice_id = i.id and fa.owner_id=pi.fi_id
join assets sa on sa.invoice_id = i.id and sa.owner_id=pi.supplier_id;
```

The corresponding Explain Analyze is :

```
Nested Loop  (cost=36.94..70919.65 rows=505 width=793) (actual time=0.263..1729.519 rows=267238 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=36.79..70806.58 rows=505 width=718) (actual time=0.261..1405.417 rows=267238 loops=1)
         Join Filter: ((i.id = fa.invoice_id) AND (pi.fi_id = fa.owner_id))
         Rows Removed by Join Filter: 400287
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=36.37..69201.99 rows=2567 width=626) (actual time=0.255..772.895 rows=248735 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (pi.supplier_id = seller_organization.id)
               ->  Hash Join  (cost=27.52..68973.45 rows=15977 width=551) (actual time=0.202..672.442 rows=248735 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: ((sa.owner_id = pi.supplier_id) AND (i.program_id = pi.program_id))
                     ->  Merge Join  (cost=1.29..63781.02 rows=667525 width=288) (actual time=0.021..496.274 rows=667525 loops=1)
                           Merge Cond: (i.id = sa.invoice_id)
                           ->  Index Scan using invoices_pkey on invoices i  (cost=0.42..27363.52 rows=249447 width=196) (actual time=0.004..60.598 rows=249440 loops=1)
                           ->  Index Scan using index_assets_invoice on assets sa  (cost=0.42..27450.72 rows=667525 width=92) (actual time=0.014..147.276 rows=667525 loops=1)
                     ->  Hash  (cost=20.09..20.09 rows=409 width=263) (actual time=0.176..0.176 rows=409 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 133kB
                           ->  Seq Scan on program_infos pi  (cost=0.00..20.09 rows=409 width=263) (actual time=0.001..0.064 rows=409 loops=1)
               ->  Hash  (cost=5.60..5.60 rows=260 width=75) (actual time=0.049..0.049 rows=260 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 27kB
                     ->  Seq Scan on endeavour_organizations seller_organization  (cost=0.00..5.60 rows=260 width=75) (actual time=0.006..0.019 rows=260 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using index_assets_owner_invoice on assets fa  (cost=0.42..0.57 rows=4 width=92) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=3 loops=248735)
               Index Cond: (invoice_id = sa.invoice_id)
   ->  Index Scan using endeavour_organizations_pkey on endeavour_organizations obligor_organization  (cost=0.15..0.21 rows=1 width=75) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=267238)
         Index Cond: (id = pi.buyer_id)
 Planning time: 3.194 ms
 Execution time: 1740.875 ms
(24 rows)
```

Indexes are on `pi.program_id`, `pi.fi_id`, `pi.supplier_id`, `asset.invoice_id`, `i.program_id`

I am not able to understand why its doing nested loop. Please let me know if something else is needed.

Comment: Are you sure the nested loop is a bad choice? How fast is the statement if you use `set enable_nestloop = off` and then run `explain (analyze, verbose)` What is your setting for `work_mem`? does this change if you increase it? What is the output of `select version()`

Comment: Please add the index definitions. And Please don't use `*` select only the columns you actually need.

Comment: A nested loop join is chosen because the result size of the inner joins is underestimated. You may be able to gain half a second or so by setting `enable_nestloop` to `off`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: No, I am not saying nested loop is a bad choice.  I just want to know opinions. With `enable_nestloop = off` , the time actually increases. Version is **PostgreSQL 9.6.0 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) 5.3.1 20160413, 64-bit**.

Comment: "*I am not able to understand why its doing nested loop*" - because apparently that is the fastest way of doing it - as you just verified by disabling nested loops

Comment: Thats fine. So not possible to improve it?

Comment: @Nikhil, as it looks for me, the biggest cost is because of `Merge Join`, have you tried the same query with `enable_mergejoin` set to `off`?